# Slavery on Exodus 21 verse 20-21

Tags: bible, exodus, slavery

Does this verse permit slavery on the Holy Bible?

> Anyone who beats their male or female slave with a rod must be
>   punished if the slave dies as a direct result, but they are not to be
>   punished if the slave recovers after a day or two, since the slave is
>   their property.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. We like to ask all of our new users to view our [about] page and [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). It's just so you can understand how this site works and is not a reflection on the quality of your post. Thanks for posting.

Comment: The site already has [quite a few slavery questions](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=slavery).